# Why should I use generic views?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I was going through the Django 1.10 tutorial when I came upon [this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/#use-generic-views-less-code-is-better):

> Generic views abstract common patterns to the point where you don’t even need to write Python code to write an app.

It talks about how you can simplify your code to make writing your views easier by using generic views. My question is, **why should I use generic views?** 
I feel like a lot of the examples shown are very implicit views which I dislike in comparison to writing out the views "manually".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states

> Use generic views: Less code is better

More implicit means lesser line of codes. It is fine using the functional view as it will be more explicit. Lesser codes means your maintaining effort is minimal.

You just have different value with the framework author, it is fine.